# What to avoid when writing a war scenario?

Tags: fiction, combat

For example my story is placed in WW3, well the second chapter is placed in WW3, and yet I struggle, to write a plausible WW3 scenario. I have planned to make it about false flags committed by one person to create tension between many countries which then collapse and trigger a third World War.

But what are some things to avoid when writing a World War scenario or a war scenario in general?

Comment: Hi JDogge, welcome to Writers.SE! We're a Q&A site, and we have certain guidelines for questions. Particularly, we focus on practical difficulties you run into. Here, you've written that you're struggling, but you haven't written what you're struggling *with*, which makes it very hard to advise you! And you ask for an all-purpose list of "things to avoid," which is very broad, and makes it hard to answer your question.

Comment: So I'm going to put the question on-hold temporarily, so you can edit and tell us where it is you're stuck, what it is you're having difficulty with. Feel free to chat here in the comments - we can help you narrow down and hammer out exactly what's bugging you.

Answer (score 3):

**Possibly, You Are Struggling With the Scope**

It sounds as if you are struggling with the scope of writing about a huge war.

I'm thinking your question might be better as something like:

*How do I deal with writing on a grand scale event such as an entire war?*

**Find the Proper Point of View (POV)**

The answer is that because a war is so large, you cannot write about all of it.  It would take a parchment the size of the sky.
However, if you focus on a specific POV within the grand scale the story will most likely become much better anyways, because:

1. it will focus on one person's experience
2. The reader will live the story vicariously through that character
3. Sympathetic and emotional moments will come through the character and absorb the reader **more completely than an overview narrative** that just tells about events happening.

**Focus On Character & Scene Within the Larger Story (War)**

If you will focus on one character and one scene you will find it much easier to write.

**Individual Scenes Add Up to Story (The War)**

Finally, your individual scenes with transitional narratives will sew it all together and the reader will experience it as one war.

**Small Example**

**Scene**: Pvt Jones stationed at front leads charge into robot caves.

**Scene**: Corporal Samson calls in airstrike from field command HQ

**Scene**: Combat unit disembarks water crawlers at beach.  Many are killed and Officer Smith is shellshocked but goes berserk leading her people to take the west caves.

**Write Each Scene With Detailed Precision**

> Jones pushed a button on her communicator, "There are only three of
> us, but we're moving into southwest cave."
>
> As Jones stepped into the
> cave, she heard something to her left, then saw the robot's red
> glowing eyes.  She dropped to her knee, brought up her 44 caliber
> pistol and fired. The robot's head exploded.
>
> "Don't sneak up on
> me," Jones said.  "I don't like sneaky robots."

Write the next scene.
These will all add up to the entire story and war for your readers.
Readers are smart and add it all up for us.

What we (authors) don't write, the reader's imagination writes for us. :)
Their brains fill in the blanks.